# Problem with initiating form fields as instance variables in form classes

Tags: python-3.x, flask-wtforms

Not able to have a instance variable of WTForm fields as instance variables

This is to have multiple number (flexible) of field which can be cascaded to increase number of fields.

The program is working fine for a simple class and one login field and one password field if the field are class variables..

## project/app/froms.py

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username')
    password = PasswordField('Password')
```

if the fields are initiated in the constructors, the program is not working. the error of the program is

## project/app/forms.py

```
class TestLoginForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self):
        username = StringField('Username')
        password = PasswordField('Password')
```

the following are other parts of this program

```
<!-- project/app/templates/test.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <form method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>
        {{ form.username.label }}<br>
        {{ form.username(size=32) }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.password.label }}<br>
        {{ form.password(size=32) }}
    </p>
    <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

## project/app/routes.py

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template
from app.forms import TestLoginForm

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():

    form = TestLoginForm()
    return render_template('test.html', form=form)
```

## project/app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'you-will-never-guess'

from app import routes
```

## project/ website.py

```
from app import app
```

Please let me know what are the concepts I need to learn and advise about possible way to get the outcome of the problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\Documents\Flask_testWebsite\app\routes.py", line 13, in index
    return render_template('test.html', form=form)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 135, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 117, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\css120807\Documents\Flask_testWebsite\app\templates\test.html", line 10, in top-level template code
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 135, in hidden_tag
    u'\n'.join(text_type(f) for f in hidden_fields(fields or self))
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 135, in <genexpr>
    u'\n'.join(text_type(f) for f in hidden_fields(fields or self))
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 125, in hidden_fields
    for f in fields:
  File "C:\Users\css120807\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wtforms\form.py", line 57, in __iter__
    return iter(itervalues(self._fields))
AttributeError: 'TestLoginForm' object has no attribute '_fields'
```

Answer (score 0):

In quickstart there is an example of creating forms:
https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#creating-forms

There are class fields, not instance (in __init__).

If I understand correctly you would like to inherit fields from parent class, why not like this:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])

class AnotherForm(MyForm):
    surname = StringField('surname', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

then you can use two forms in your routes.py:

```
form = MyForm()
```

with csrf token and name field

or

```
form = AnotherForm()
```

with everything from MyForm (csrf + name) and surname

Comment: Thank you for responding... this helped me search in a different direction.. :)